# GNU-linker cannot find Windows directory

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, linker-errors

I am using GNU toolchain in a windows environment... My toolchain was pre-built with built-in CYGWIN dlls, so i did not install CYGWIN...

My question is: how do i specify my lib path in the linker command for GNU-linker..
Below is my Makefile and when i run it, it returns a message saying the path cannot be found...

```
...
LD = arm-elf-ld
AR = arm-elf-ar
...
...
libdir = C:\My Project\My library\

CCFLAGS = -c -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O0 -g -Wall
ASMFLAGS = -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb --gdwarf-2
LDFLAGS = -T mylinkerscript.ld -L $(libdir)
ARFLAGS = rc

all: m3.elf
m3.elf: startup.o main.o libGPIO.a
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) startup.o main.o -lGPIO -o $@
...
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Including the actual, exact, error message is generally helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential problems I see in your code:

1. Spaces in the path
2. Cygwin usually requires paths to be separated by forward slash '/', not backslash.

Thus, try two things:

```
  LDFLAGS = -T mylinkerscript.ld -L "$(libdir)"
```

i.e. add quotes to mark it a single argument not separate words. And try satisfy Cygwins backslash issues:

```
  libdir = /cygdrive/c/My Project/My library
```

or

```
  libdir = "C:\\My Project\\My library"
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked now if i use the following ways:

```
libdir = C:\\My\ Project\\My\ library
```

or

```
libdir = C:/My\ Project/My\ library
```

or

```
libdir = /cygdrive/c/My\ Project/My\ library
```